# Prove eigenvalue for $A^2 + I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a proof I've been trying to figure out since the problem was presented to me.

We are given that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for a matrix $A$ and the vector $u$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.  The problem asks to us to prove that ${\lambda}^2 + 1$ is an eigenvalue for $A^2 + I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I am not quite sure where to start.  My first instinct was to somehow manipulate $Au = {\lambda}u$, but I'm not quite sure what to do with it.

Any ideas for this one? It's certainly an interesting problem, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$Au=\lambda u \implies A^2u=\lambda Au=\lambda^2u.$$

Then, letting $I$ be the identity:

$$A^2u +Iu=\lambda^2u +Iu \iff (A^2+I)u=(\lambda^2+1)u,$$

since obviously $Iu=u$.